# Getting x Position attribute for every "rect" with a specific class

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js, svg

I am having trouble getting the x attr for each "rect" I have in a given SVG that has the class ".selectdOrder". I want to use the x positions to draw lines in another svg. When I try to use what I have below- the x value comes back as undefined. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here is the code below:

```
let orderRect = this.svg.select('#pat_rect_line')

  .selectAll('.orderRect')
  .data([ordersInfo]);
  let orderRectEnter = orderRect.enter()
  .append('g')
  .classed('orderRect', true);
  orderRect = orderRectEnter.merge(orderRect);

  let rects = orderRect.selectAll('rect')
  .data((d) => d);
  let rectsEnter = rects.enter()
  .append('rect');
  rects = rectsEnter.merge(rects);
  rects.attr('class', getClassAssignment('ORDER_CATALOG_TYPE'))
  .attr('class', getClassAssignment('ORDER_STATUS'))
  .attr('x', (g) => this.timeScale(g.diff))
  .attr('y', 0)
  .attr('width', this.orderBar.width)
  .attr('height', this.orderBar.height)

  //this is the mousclick event that greys rects
    .on('click', d => {
      this.svg.selectAll('rects');
      if (this.currentlySelectedName === undefined) {
        this.currentlySelectedName = d.ORDER_MNEMONIC;
       console.log(this.currentlySelectedName);
       rects.selectAll('.selectedOrder')
       for(let rect of rects){console.log(rect.x);}

      } else {
        this.currentlySelectedName = undefined;

      }

      this.drawPatOrderRects();

      var selectedGroup = d3.selectAll('.selectedOrder');

     console.log(selectedGroup.size());
     let xPosition = rects.currentlySelectedName.x;
     console.log(xPosition);

  })//end the mousclick event that shows the graph
```

I am assigning the ".selectedOrder" class to a rect if the order name matches the one that is selected on a mouse click. This works and it logs the name of the order in the console and how many selected orders there are. I am just having trouble accessing the x position!

thank you!

jen

Answer (score 0):

I may be misreading your question. I am also answering with a simpler set of base code.

If you have multiple `rects` with unknown x coordinates, and you want an array that holds all those x coordinates for the selected `rects`, then you could use code such as:

```
var x = selection.nodes().map(function(d) { return d.getAttribute("x"); });
```

As demonstrated below:

```js
var data = [];

for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  data.push({ 
     x: d3.randomNormal(250,125)() ,
     y: d3.randomNormal(100,50)()
     });
 }
 
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width",500)
  .attr("height",200);
  
 
var rects = svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("y",function(d) { return d.y; })
  .attr("x",function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("width",10)
  .attr("height",10)
  .attr("fill", function(d,i) { return d3.schemeCategory20[i]; });

// Get the x attribute of each rectangle.
console.log( rects.nodes().map(function(d) { return d.getAttribute("x"); }) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.9.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

If your selection holds only one `rect`, then you can get that property with:

```
var x = selection.attr("x");
```

```js
var data = [];

for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  data.push({ 
     x: d3.randomNormal(250,125)() ,
     y: d3.randomNormal(100,50)()
     });
 }
 
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width",500)
  .attr("height",200);
  
 
var rects = svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("y",function(d) { return d.y; })
  .attr("x",function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("width",10)
  .attr("height",10)
  .attr("fill", function(d,i) { return d3.schemeCategory20[i]; });

// Get the x attribute of a rectangle (first in the selection).
console.log( rects.attr("x") );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.9.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Also, if you are trying to append a feature (`line`) for each selected feature (`rect`), then you could try something along the following lines (no pun intended):

*This could be made more d3-ish, but I am minimizing the code changes from the examples above and feel four snippets might be a bit excessive. Also, the new lines do not need to be in the same svg (your question states: "I want to use the x positions to draw lines in another svg.")*

```js
var data = [];

for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  data.push({ 
     x: d3.randomNormal(250,125)() ,
     y: d3.randomNormal(100,50)()
     });
 }
 
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width",500)
  .attr("height",200);
  
 
var rects = svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("y",function(d) { return d.y; })
  .attr("x",function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("width",10)
  .attr("height",10)
  .attr("fill", function(d,i) { return d3.schemeCategory20[i]; });

// Append a line from each square to the origin:
var lines = svg.selectAll("line")
  .data(rects.nodes())  // add one line for each item in the selection
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .style("stroke", "black")
  .attr("x1",0)
  .attr("y1",0)
  .attr("x2",function(d) { return d.getAttribute("x"); })
  .attr("y2",function(d) { return d.getAttribute("y"); });
  
// Sure, let's make the lines dance to mousemove
svg.on("mousemove", function() {
  lines.attr("x1",d3.mouse(this)[0])
    .attr("y1",d3.mouse(this)[1]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.9.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey Thanks so much for the thorough reply!! I really appreciate it- I am just running into some problems selecting/ using .map() on the selected objects.

Comment: When I attempted to use .map() with this-            'let rectX = this.svg.selectAll('rects').selectAll('.selectedOrder').filter( (d) => {return d.getAttribute('x'); });
          console.log(rectX);' It says .selectAll().selectAll().map is not a function. The filter however doesn't throw any errors but the array returns empty. Any ideas what might be wrong?? Thanks again!

Comment: you need the nodes (the elements themselves, not the data) - not just the selection (selection.nodes()) - which is v4 functionality. This can be done in v3, but requires much less intuitive code.